# Blogger multiple label search

Tags: search, label, blogger, blogspot

on any blogspot blog, if you click on a label, it will do a search for you on all the blog, showing stuff tagged with that label.

is there a way to do that again? i mean to search for 2 labels. I want to see all the posts that have both labels.

is there something built in?

if not, can I do something about that on my blog? something custom?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i try it too..

search it on your blog...
type "label:first_label label:second_label" without quotes...
here ex:[Like my blog](http://newhdd.blogspot.com/search/?q=label:1tb%20label%3aWD)

hope it can help... :]

Comment: If I have three labels "a", "b" and "c"
If I have to filter the posts labeled with "a" and "c" not "b"
How can I do this?
What if some posts label with "a" and also has label "b"? How to ignore this post?

Comment: This shows the posts with either label, does it not? What about showing only posts with both labels?

Answer (score 6):

this will work

```
<blog-URL>/search/?q=label:LABEL1|label:LABEL2
```

Answer (score 5):

another method:

```
/search/label/tiger+animal%20kingdom
```

note:

```
label1 = tiger
label2 = animal kingdom (with space)

+ (plus) work as label separator
%20 (space url-entities)
```

Comment: This is the correct way and is a better answer than the current one.

Answer (score -1):

The only way readers can look for two labels is through search.You can manually search for two labels and add the link to the results...

Comment: But is there some advanced search option to have the search only search labels and not post content?

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski: That's not supported, it seems: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=582